# How to create my own command handler for library shell app in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a shell application for a litte digital library and I want to be able to get some commands for importing books in library from users like this:

```
ADD { book_title } TO { library_id } WITH { COUNT } RECORDS
```

It is like sql queries but in my own way.
So, I want to create this system to get my data from queries that the user wrote.

If any one can help me I will be appreciative.

Comment: The new 3.10 [pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) feature could come handy, but your question is quite vague and broad

Comment: In fact I want to create my own sql query handler without any librarys or other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a [Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) you could use [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) for the CLI.

For a [Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop (REPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) which is more like an *interactive shell* (like known by IPython or most SQL clients) you could use [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) from the Python standard library or [`cmd2`](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

#### Example of CLI using Click

In your case you would use [Multi Command Chaining](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#multi-command-chaining) and [Contexts](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts).

Example: `script.py`

```py
import click

# ADD { book_title } TO { library_id } WITH { COUNT } RECORDS

@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        click.echo('I was invoked without subcommand')
    else:
        click.echo(f"I am about to invoke {ctx.invoked_subcommand}")


@cli.command(name='ADD')
@click.argument('book_title')
@click.pass_context
def add(ctx, book_title):
    """ADD {book_title}"""
    click.echo(f"add book {book_title}")
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj['book'] = book_title


@cli.command(name='TO')
@click.argument('library_id')
@click.pass_context
def to(ctx, library_id):
    """TO {library_id}"""
    click.echo(f"to {library_id}")
    click.echo(f"Book is {ctx.obj['book']}")
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj['library'] = library_id

@cli.command(name='WITH')
@click.argument('count')
@click.pass_context
def withRecords(ctx, count):
    """WITH {count} records"""
    click.echo(f"with {count} records")
    click.echo(f"Book is {ctx.obj['book']}")
    click.echo(f"Library is {ctx.obj['library']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli(obj={})
```

When invoked like `python3 script.py ADD title TO library WITH 3` it prints:

```
I am about to invoke *
add book title
to library
Book is title
with 3 records
Book is title
Library is library
```

Comment: thank you very much, but how can i access to the parameter like book_title please show me that. because i want to write them in a txt file

Comment: @arronwhite like any function parameter by its name: `book_title`